# VBA Syntactic Sugar

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I use VBA in my work every day, but I didn't know about Range syntactic sugar. I just knew last month when I saw MSDN Range page. I tried to find an article with this features, but I didn’t find any.

Does someone know if VBA has more syntactic sugar than this

Range:`Range("A4:C100")` to `[A4:C100]`

or

Range: `Range("MY_DATE")` to `[MY_DATE]`

Comment: You might find this to be worthwhile reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070863/hidden-features-of-vba

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For ranges

These all do the same thing:

`Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(2, 2)).Select`

`Range("B1:B2").Select`

```
Dim rngB As Range
Set rngB = Range("B1:B2")
rngB.Select
```

`[B1:B2].Select`

---

### For strings

You don't have many options

```
Dim strA As String
strA = "hello"
```

`strA = strA + "world"` and
`strA = strA & "world"` do the same thing (ampersand is preferred)

`strA &= "world"` and `strA += "world"`  don't work.

---

### For worksheets

You can usually work with the actual default sheet with number, rather than what the sheet is named:

```
Worksheets("Name").Activate
Sheets("Name").Activate
'Worksheet "Name" is Sheet1 object
Sheet1.Activate
```

---

### For worksheet formulas/functions

[From Excellll's Answer](https://superuser.com/a/708388/116196) for completeness:

> Another syntactic shortcut is for accessing and evaluating worksheet
>   functions. You can use brackets to evaluate a formula as if it were on
>   the worksheet rather than stringing together a cumbersome VBA
>   statement.
>
> ```
> Sub sugartest()
> 'long version
> MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1"))
> 'short version
> MsgBox [AVERAGE(A1:D1)]
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Thanks. For string concatenation I use my StringFormat() that works like C# style. https://github.com/makah/ExcelHelper/blob/master/Helper.bas - Sub comments in portuguese :-(

Comment: Something for Sheets() ?

Comment: @Makah sheets can be referred to as the sheet they are by default (Sheet#) rather than title, if you refer to the object. See my edit.

Comment: You can also assign a range to an array variable and vice-versa.

Answer (score 6):

Another syntactic shortcut is for accessing and evaluating worksheet functions. You can use brackets to evaluate a formula as if it were on the worksheet rather than stringing together a cumbersome VBA statement.

```
Sub sugartest()
'long version
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1"))
'short version
MsgBox [AVERAGE(A1:D1)]
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not know this and it's AWESOME +1

Comment: Uuuh, this is nice!