# Why is my constructed formula giving different results than the same formula as UDF in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Here's a long formula to calculate  distance between two coordinates points on Earth

> =ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-LAT1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-LAT2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-LAT1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-LAT2)) *COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) *6371

As it is a bit cumbersome to use inside other formulas, I wrote a user defined function for that.

> Function DistXY(Lat1 As Single, Lng1 As Single, Lat2 As Single, Lng2
>   As Single) As Single
>
> DistXY = WorksheetFunction.Acos(Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 -
>   Lat1)) * Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat2)) +
>   Sin(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat1)) *
>   Sin(WorksheetFunction.Radians(90 - Lat2)) *
>   Cos(WorksheetFunction.Radians(Lng1 - Lng2))) * 6371
>
> End function

As you can see, they're exactly the same. As there's no Acos ou Radians functions in VBA, it even uses the "worksheetFunction" method.

Why is that when I apply theses formula to the same pair of XY coordinates, I get different results ?

For example:

From ABC    45.4960674,-73.514446   to  XYZ 43.5369,-71.8592

**DistXY()** results:    254.313156128

**Long formula method**: 254.313268914

Going along with the comment of @raystafarian , changing all the types to double improved the precision. But there's still a difference.

> Function DistXY(Lat1 As double, Lng1 As double, Lat2 As double, Lng2
>   As double) As double ...

New results:

**DistXY()** :           254.313268913**5060** km

**Long formula method**: 254.313268913**5250** km

Comment: I assume that this is because of rounding errors in the different stages of the calculation, and Excel and VBA handling them slightly differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using (and returning) a data type of [single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx). This will cause functions to evaluate differently if they take a different data type of default.

- [Acos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff823173.aspx) - Double
- [Cos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264404.aspx) - Double
- [Sin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278707.aspx) - Double
- [Radians](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840034.aspx) - Double

Answer (score 1):

Based on **Raystafarian's** answer:

```
Public Function DistXY(Lat1 As Double, Lng1 As Double, Lat2 As Double, Lng2 As Double) As Double
   Dim i As Double, f As Double
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

   i = 90
   f = 6371

   DistXY = wf.Acos(Cos(wf.Radians(i - Lat1)) * Cos(wf.Radians(i - Lat2)) + Sin(wf.Radians(i - Lat1)) * Sin(wf.Radians(i - Lat2)) * Cos(wf.Radians(Lng1 - Lng2))) * f
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The Dim/set to avoid writing worksheetfunction several times is a nice touch.

Comment: @P.Obertelli  Pure laziness on my part!

Comment: For maximum laziness - http://superuser.com/a/708388/116196

Comment: @Raystafarian  **WOW!!** ...................Thank you!!

Comment: @Raystafarian [There are a few quirks with `Evaluate`](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/), though...

Comment: the comments have even more value for me tban the answers . Thanks. Ps I gave the answer to Rasta as it was enough to solve the problem

Comment: @P.Obertelli  I also would award Raysta the answer................I used it in my sample code.